# Insert command not working on connection between C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have this table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE Ciudadano (  
ci int not null,  
Nombre varchar(50),  
Apellido varchar(50),  
Correo varchar(50),  
Usuario varchar(50), 
 Contrasena varchar(50),  
Localidad_cod int,  
Primary key (ci)  
)
```

I'm trying to add data to the table `Ciudadano` from Visual Studio c#, using a stored procedure called `sp_ConsultarCuenta`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ConsultarCuenta
   @ci int, @nom varchar(50), @ape varchar(50), @user varchar(50), 
   @pass varchar(50), @correo varchar(50), @loc varchar(50)
AS
   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ci,Usuario FROM Ciudadano 
                 WHERE ci = @ci OR Usuario = @user)
      DECLARE @var varchar(50)
      SET @var = (SELECT cod From Localidad Where Nombre = @loc)

      INSERT INTO Ciudadano (ci, Nombre, Apellido, Correo, Usuario, Contrasena, Localidad_cod)
      VALUES (@ci, @nom, @ape, @user, @pass, @correo, @var)
```

And on my c# code I have this:

```
public void AgregarCiudadano()
{
   string con = @"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=SistemaDeQuejas;Trusted_Connection=True";
   SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(con);

   conexion.Open();
   SqlDataAdapter Comando = new SqlDataAdapter();

   Comando.InsertCommand = conexion.CreateCommand();
   Comando.InsertCommand.CommandText = "sp_ConsultarCuenta";
   Comando.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   Comando.InsertCommand.Connection = conexion;

   Comando.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ci", SqlDbType.Int).Value = System.Convert.ToInt32(ci);
   Comando.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@nom", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Nombre;
   Comando.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ape", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Apellido;
   Comando.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Usuario;
   Comando.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Contrasena;
   Comando.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@correo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Correo;
   Comando.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@loc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Localidad;

   conexion.Close();  
}
```

What I'm doing is a Web form, and that method is called by a button on the form. But when I run it and press the button it doesn't throw any error but the data I'm trying to insert into the database table is not inserting at all. Is there something wrong on my code?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks marc_s...didn't know about that actually!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cYou can do this to run your insert command in a simple way

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   connection.Open();

   using (var command = new SqlCommand("sp_ConsultarCuenta", connection))
   {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", params.Nombre);

        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }

   connection.Close();
 }
```

Comment: This is a bit crude. I would probably create a generic method to handle my command and then just pass the procedure name along with a list of param values.

Comment: I just ran your code and it throws the following error: `Error converting data type nvarchar to int`. On the `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`; line

Comment: Use correct data type in your param. I presume your Nombre field is a number and you are trying to supply nvarchar in it. Lemme know whether or not that's the case.

Comment: How did it go? Don't forget to let us know :).

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't answer earlier, I was busy with other stuff. My Nombre field is actually a varchar field that means "Name", but my number field in this case is "ci". How should I put them?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show your code please? Need to see how you are doing it which is throwing that exception. MEthod AddWithValue's second parameter takes an object so unless you are supplying a string it shouldn't throw any exception.

Comment: Also, if ci is primary key then they way you are handling it is not really correct and calls for tons of issues. Make it identity so that you don't have to create it yourself and then add checks like the one you have to see whether or not it exists already.

Comment: Hi, sorry I was lost over here. I've noticed that I had a mistake on my Store procedure and I just fixed it, so your code worked perfectly! Thank you very much! My mistake.